# How best to map split capitalise and join a hash's key

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
industries = {'consultancy_services' => 0, 'manufacturing' => 1, 'retailing_services' => 2}
```

whose keys I want to split by an underscore if there is one, each of whose resulting element I want to capitalise.

Is there a nicer way of doing this than:

```
Hash[industries.map { |k,v| [k.to_str.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' '), k] }]
```

V helpful responses, thank you. #humanize seems like neatest way, as below:

```
industries.map {|k,_| k.humanize }.to_h
```

Comment: If you're running this in Rails, it would have added `#titleize` to your string classes, or `#humanize`.

Comment: Brilliant Jack, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave out the `to_str` since your keys are strings anyway. (And besides, no other class than [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) in the Ruby core library implements [`to_str`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_str) anyway, so if the keys are not strings, you'll get an exception.)

Also, you can rename your `v` block parameter to `_` since you are not using it. `_` is just as valid a name as `v`, but it is a convention that says to other programmers "I'm not using this thing", and Ruby tools know about this convention and will e.g. not generate an "unused variable" warning.

And lastly, you could use [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_h) instead of [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

```
industries.map {|k, _| [ k.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' '), k] }.to_h
#=> { 'Consultancy Services' => 'consultancy_services', 'Manufacturing' => 'manufacturing', 'Retailing Services' => 'retailing_services' }
```

If you have access to ActiveSupport, you could use [`ActiveSupport::Inflector::titleize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize):

```
require 'active_support/inflector'
industries.map {|k, _| [ ActiveSupport::Inflector.titleize(k), k] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
industries
.keys
.group_by{|k| k.gsub(/[^_]+/, &:capitalize).tr("_", " ")}
.transform_values(&:first)
```

Result:

```
{
  "Consultancy Services"=>"consultancy_services", 
  "Manufacturing"=>"manufacturing",
  "Retailing Services"=>"retailing_services"
}
```